# I am writing a Selenium script in Firefox but I am getting "Untrusted Certificate"

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver

written a code like this

```
FirefoxProfile profile=new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("url");
```

Not working in firefox how to resolve this one.

Answer (score 0):

You're not creating the driver with the profile - you're creating it with an empty constructor. Try `WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver(profile);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Selenium WebDriverJS

```
var WebDriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var driver = new WebDriver.Builder().withCapabilities(
    WebDriver.Capabilities.firefox()
).build();

driver.get('url');
```