# Selenium Why setting acceptuntrustedcertificates to true for firefox driver doesn't work?

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I'm developping some selenium tests and I face an important issue because I didn't found a "real" solution when I test my site with secure connection (**HTTPS**). All solutions I found on stackoverflow are out of date or doesn't work:

1. [I am writing a Selenium script in Firefox but I am getting "Untrusted Certificate"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39835284/i-am-writing-a-selenium-script-in-firefox-but-i-am-getting-untrusted-certificat)
2. [How to disable Firefox's untrusted connection warning using Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16879566/how-to-disable-firefoxs-untrusted-connection-warning-using-selenium)
3. [Handling UntrustedSSLcertificates using WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933871/handling-untrustedsslcertificates-using-webdriver)

The only workaround I have is to use the nightly mozilla release as indicated on github: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/420

```
        private IWebDriver driver;
        private string baseURL;
        private FirefoxOptions ffOptions;
        private IWait<IWebDriver> wait;

        [SetUp]
        public void SetupTest()
        {
            ffOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
            ffOptions.BrowserExecutableLocation = @"D:\AppData\Local\Nightly\firefox.exe";
            FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
            profile.AssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer = false;
            profile.AcceptUntrustedCertificates = true;
            ffOptions.Profile = profile;            
            ffOptions.LogLevel = FirefoxDriverLogLevel.Info;
            driver = new FirefoxDriver(FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(), ffOptions, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

            //[...]           
        }
```

Configuration:

- **Firefox v47.0.1, v49.0.2, v51.0.1, v52.0b9** (i tried these differents versions)
- **geckodriver  0.14**
- **selenium 3.1.0**

Does anyone have a solution to avoid using nightly release ?

For information I have access only to stackoverflow and github due to my internet policy, and please don't suggest me to use chrome!

Thank for your help!

Comment: "doesn't work?" means nothing,  please put the errors and log

Comment: There is no error litteraly speaking because while i'm accessing to my page which is a secure page (https) I face the page "Your connection is not secure". This indicated me the certificate is not trusted/not valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, it's a bug on the geckodriver. You can find it [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/420)!

Answer (score 1):

Setting the `AcceptInsecureCertificates` property to `true` in the `FirefoxOptions` fixed this problem for me. Here's what my initialization looked like after this change:

```
        var profile = new FirefoxProfile();
        profile.DeleteAfterUse = true;
        profile.SetPreference("network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris", LocalURL);
        profile.SetPreference("network.automatic-ntlm-auth.allow-non-fqdn", true);
        profile.SetPreference("webdriver_accept_untrusted_certs", true);
        // Only setting this property to true did not work for me either
        profile.AcceptUntrustedCertificates = true;
        profile.AssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer = false;

        return new FirefoxDriver(new FirefoxOptions
        {
            Profile = profile,
            // When I also added this line, it DID work
            AcceptInsecureCertificates = true
        });
```

Comment: Where did you put this code?

Comment: @WolfgangBlessen in the SetUp method!
ejoshuas-stand-with-ukraine thank for the update :)