# How to get Selenium and Geckodriver to ignore unsecure locally served webpage on local execution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, geckodriver

I have the latest geckodriver (0.18.0) and webdriver (3.5.1.0). I am running Selenium tests locally and remotely. When I run my tests remotely against an HTTPS site, they run fine.

I use the following references:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using System;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using Browser.Core.Framework.Resources;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
using System.Reflection;
```

My remote code that works is:

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = null;

caps = FirefoxOptions.ToCapabilities() as DesiredCapabilities;
caps.SetCapability("acceptInsecureCerts", true);
if (FirefoxProfile != null)
{
caps.SetCapability(FirefoxDriver.ProfileCapabilityName, FirefoxProfile.ToBase64String());
}

caps.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Version, null);
caps.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Platform, null);

var buildNumber = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
caps.SetCapability("build", buildNumber);
caps.SetCapability("name", TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name);

Console.WriteLine("http://10.32.26.16:8888/wd/hub");

IWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://10.32.26.16:8888/wd/hub"), caps, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://rcpsc.releasecandidate-community360qa.net/login.aspx?action=enablelogin");
```

When I run locally, I can not seem to bypass the "Your connection is not secure" message that firefox throws. Here is my code for running local, which doesnt work:

```
var service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"C:\seleniumdrivers", "geckodriver.exe");
service.FirefoxBinaryPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe";

var options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.Profile = new BaseFirefoxProfile();

IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(service, options, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30000));
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://rcpsc.releasecandidate-community360qa.net/login.aspx?action=enablelogin");
```

Here goes the custom firefoxprofile that is referenced:

```
public class BaseFirefoxProfile : FirefoxProfile
{
    public BaseFirefoxProfile()
        : base()
    {
        AcceptUntrustedCertificates = true;
    }
}
```

When running locally, I get the "Your connection is not secure" message and the test fails. When I debug and view the firefoxprofile, it says AcceptUntrustedCertificates is correctly set to true but it doesnt work

Comment: You can probably find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42583795/selenium-why-setting-acceptuntrustedcertificates-to-true-for-firefox-driver-does

Comment: This links to the GitHub which has an issue that is Closed, but the thread does not indicate it is resolved. There has to be a workaround or a fix.